# Angular animation doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: angular

I am using the below code to gradually hide a DIV in Angular 2. This perfectly works in Chrome and Microsoft Edge. But the same thing doesn't work in Firefox and DIV stays visible. Do I need to add or edit anything to make this work in Firefox.

```
  animations: [
  trigger('toggleDiv', [
  state('false', style({})),
  state('true', style({ maxHeight: 0, padding: 0, display: 'none', 
  overflow: 'hidden' })),
  transition('* => *', animate('300ms ease')),
  ])
 ]
 })
```

Answer (score 4):

The exact problem is with `padding: 0`, **remove it** and the animation will close and work again in firefox. I don't know the exact details of this behaviour, but it seems firefox and angular animations don't work really well with some styles (in this case, padding).

A workaround to keep padding at 0, is using

```
padding-top: 0;
padding-right: 0
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-left: 0;
```

Comment: This is unfortunately an old angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16330

Comment: Yes, it's still present in the last build (9.1.2). But this workaround is still working at least. @sburnicki

Comment: The same thing applies for other shorthand properties like `gap`, just use `column-gap` and `row-gap`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations), pre-6.0 requires a polyfill for browsers that don't [natively support the web animation API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation). To add the polyfill, install [web-animations-js](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) and add the following to polyfills.js

`require('web-animations-js');`